# Does SQL Server's is_nullable mean anything at all?

Tags: sql-server, datatypes, null, sql-server-2019, metadata

SQL Server has a type flag called `is_nullable` you can see it on `sys.types`. Currently, (SQL Server 2019) it's only set to `FALSE` two types, `sys.timestamp` and `sys.sysname`. On `sys.timestamp` this type seems to accept `null`. On `sys.sysname` it does not. Is there any explanation of this behavior?

You can see these types with

```
SELECT * FROM sys.types WHERE is_nullable = 0;  
SELECT TYPEPROPERTY('timestamp', 'AllowsNull');  -- returns 0
```

And you can use it like this,

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( a sys.timestamp );
INSERT INTO foo (a) VALUES ( null );
```

Note this won't work if you use `sys.sysname`

> ```
> Msg 515 Level 16 State 2 Line 1
> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'a', table 'dbo.foo'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
> Msg 3621 Level 0 State 0 Line 1
> The statement has been terminated.
> ```

It also will not work if you [create a user-defined data type which is `NOT NULL`,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/create-a-user-defined-data-type-alias?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
CREATE TYPE bar FROM int NOT NULL;
```

Is this just a hint for the user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me rephrase the question, to make sure we are on the same page:

Meta-data for the timestamp type say that it doesn't accept NULL, but if you create a table without specifying nullability you can specify NULL for that column on INSERT. Why?

If you SELECT from the table, you will see that the value isn't null after the INSERT. You have the generated "timestamp" (or rowversion, if you prefer that name). I.e., NULL on INSERT is meaningless, it means that the "default" (so to speak) is used.

One can go into a discussion whether this meta-data property for the timestamp type should reflect whether we can specify null on INSERT or whether we can in the end actually *have* NULL in that column.

I guess we would have to been present when Sybase designed the system tables some decades ago to be able to know that answer. I wasn't. :-)

So, in short: the column of a timestamp type doesn't allow null in the table, and based on that one can argue that the meta-data is correct.

(As an aside, I first though this was a backward compatibility thing, so I fired up a 6.5 version of SQL Server to test on. And I almost fired up a version 4.2 as well. But then I did a SELECT and it wasn't until then that I noticed that the value wasn't NULL at all.)

Here's the T-SQL I played with (on 2019), FWIW:

```
USE tempdb

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myTable;
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS myTypeYesNull;
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS myTypeNoNull;

CREATE TYPE myTypeYesNull FROM int NULL;
CREATE TYPE myTypeNoNull FROM int NOT NULL;
GO

CREATE TABLE myTable (yesNull myTypeYesNull, noNull myTypeNoNull, ts timestamp, sname sysname);
GO

SELECT name, is_nullable FROM sys.types WHERE name IN ('myTypeYesNull', 'myTypeNoNull', 'timestamp', 'sysname')

SELECT 
 COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('myTable'), 'yesNull', 'AllowsNull') AS yesNull
,COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('myTable'), 'noNull', 'AllowsNull') AS noNull
,COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('myTable'), 'ts', 'AllowsNull') AS ts
,COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('myTable'), 'sname', 'AllowsNull') AS sname;

--The ts column accepts NULL even though table meta-data states differently
INSERT INTO myTable (yesNull, noNull, ts, sname)
VALUES(NULL, 1, NULL, 'x')

SELECT * FROM myTable

----------------------------------------------------------------------

--Code executable on really old versions
DROP TABLE myTable 
GO
SELECT name, allownulls FROM systypes WHERE name = 'sysname'
CREATE TABLE myTable(ts timestamp NULL)
GO

--Doesn't fail on 6.5
INSERT INTO myTable(ts) VALUES(null)
SELECT * FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 7):

The answer to your question is yes.

That column specifies the default nullability of a data type, which can be important if the user doesn't express a preference e.g. in a `CREATE TABLE` statement with an explicit `NULL` or `NOT NULL` specification. Sadly, that information is only present in the documentation for the old compatibility view [`sys.systypes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-systypes-transact-sql):

> **allownulls** (bit)
>
> Indicates the default nullability for this data type. This default value is overridden by if nullability is specified by using `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE`.|

For example, one can override the default `NOT NULL` behaviour of the `sysname` type:

```
DECLARE @T table (s sysname NULL);
INSERT @T (s) VALUES (NULL);
SELECT s FROM @T AS T;
```

| s |
| --- |
| NULL |

The `timestamp` type (preferred name [`rowversion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql)) has additional special behaviours due to its intended use to detect row changes. See [this other answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/291427) for some more details. You can still override its nullability in the same way, but it is not possible to actually store a NULL for a timestamp/rowversion attribute.

There are several complex layers to determining attribute nullability. Rather than repeat some of that detail here, I refer you to [Why you Should Always Specify Whether a Column Accepts Nulls](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/why-you-should-always-specify-whether-a-column-accepts-nulls) by Phil Factor for background information and additional reading.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question and neither does Phil's blog as far as I can see. In fact, he seems to lead me to believe that if the datatype is not-null the column won't be either. And so does your post here _"That column specifies the default nullability of a data type"_ just be clear in this example I'm not specifying a preference, the type is not null, and when you make a table w/ column of this type you can still insert null.

Comment: It's the best answer I have for you right now. I do offer full refunds in case of dissatisfaction.